# Triggers: counting rows in a bridge table after INSERT

Tags: mysql, trigger, count, many-to-many

I'm using a trigger in order to make a Statistic Table. I have this many-to-many relationship where I have an `Order` that can have multiple `Product`'s and viceversa. So after an INSERT on `Order`, using JPA, new rows are automatically inserted in the bridge table `Order_Products`.

When in the Trigger I use

```
    SET @numOfOPs = (
        SELECT COUNT(IDOrder) 
        FROM Order_Product 
        WHERE IDOrder = NEW.ID)
```

on new entries, the count on Order_Procut seems to return 0 (or the value before the insert on Order).

Here the signature of the Trigger:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `Order_AFTER_INSERT` 
    AFTER INSERT ON `Order` 
    FOR EACH ROW
```

What could be the problem? I will add additional information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean

```
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Order_Product
       WHERE ID_Order = NEW.ID_Order )
```

What will you be doing with `@numOfOPs` after the Trigger?

Comment: Well I tried both with and without IDOrder in the COUNT() but nothing changes. My need is to use @numOfOPs in an INSERT on a statistics table, in order the have directly the count without additional queries. 
May the problem be the fact that INSERT on Order happens before the INSERT on Order_Products?

Comment: @FilippoScaramuzza - My Answer focuses on `NEW.ID_Order` versus `NEW.ID`.

Comment: Actually the field of the table `Order` is `ID`, not `ID_Order`.